# Adding an integer to a sorted ArrayList at the correct index

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Say I have a sorted list (in ascending order) like this`ArrayList<Integer> arr = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)`. There will be no duplicates in the list.

I want to add an integer to it at the correct index so that the array is still sorted after I add the element, like so: `arr.add(4) // now arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.

How do I achieve this elegantly **WITHOUT** resorting to sorting AFTER I add the element by using `Collections.sort(arr)` or something.

I'm looking for a better/more elegant solution than the one I currently have (I don't even know if it works for all cases lol):

```
int n = 4 // number I want to add to the list
boolean added = false;

for(int i < 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
   if(n < arr.get(i)) {
     arr.add(i, n)
     added = true;
     break;
   }
}

if(added == false) {
  arr.add(n)
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Will the list have duplicates?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, I forgot to mention. No duplicates in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linear search you're doing now is O(n), plus O(n) for the call to `add()`.

You can find the insertion point in O(log n) time with [`Collections.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-), then call `add()` just like you're doing now. The overall complexity will still be O(n) since O(log n + n) = O(n), but it'll be slightly faster and the code'll be a good bit shorter.

```
int i = Collections.binarySearch(arr, n);

// `n` not found. Retrieve the insertion point from the return value.
if (i < 0) {
    i = -i - 1;
}

arr.add(i, n);
```

Comment: In my most honest opinion the advantage of this answer is not so much that it is more efficient (which it is for very large lists), but rather that the code is more elegant and concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TreeSet` as an intermediary. A `TreeSet` is a binary search tree, and when you iterate through it, you get the elements in sorted order.

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(arr);
set.add(n);
arr = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd use binary search to determine the insert position.

Either wrap the built in `Collections.binarySearch` method:

```
// insert v into list if not present, maintaining order
// return whether list was updated
static boolean insert(List<Integer> list, int v)
{
    int pos = Collections.binarySearch(list, v);
    if(pos >= 0)
        return false;

    pos = -pos - 1;
    list.add(pos, v);
    return true;
}
```

Or just for interest, roll your own:

```
static boolean insert(List<Integer> list, int v)
{
    int low = 0; 
    int high = list.size();
    while(low < high)
    {
        int mid = low + (high-low)/2;
        if(list.get(mid) < v)
            low = mid+1;
        else if(list.get(mid) > v)
            high = mid;
        else
            return false;               
    }
    list.add(low, v);
    return true;
}
```